SYNAPSE Copy Activity - Pass date parameter to source from file
Source: REST API  (/RESTAdapter/XYZ/Dashboard/Advances?$top=1000&$skip=0&$keydate=2024-04-30)  
SINK: CSV 
I want to pass a list of keydates to the API from a dates.csv file in blob storage.
dates.csv 
2024-01-31,2024-02-29,2024-03-31,2024-04-30
It must append the Keydate to the end of the filenames.
Expected output is to extract multiple csv files based on a list of keydates to my blob storage. Filenames should look like
Advances2024-01-31.csv
Advances2024-02-29.csv
Advances2024-03-31.csv
Advances2024-04-30.csv
Once extracted i want to load the CSV files into SQL

Do you want append the key dates at the end of the URL? Can you provide your expected output? and Is your csv file looks like that? How are rows and columns looks in your csv file?

If your requirement is only to create Advance<date>.csv files where the dates coming from a dates.csv file, then you can follow the below approach.
given dates in a  dates.csv file as same as yours:
2024-01-31,2024-02-29,2024-03-31,2024-04-30

Now, create a delimited text dataset for the dates.csv file. Here, this file doesn't have any headers or rows. So, change the Column delimiter to different one than , and remove the First Row as header.

Give this dataset to a lookup activity and disable the First row only in the lookup activity settings. The lookup activity will give the output array like below upon debugging it.
"value": [
        {
            "Prop_0": "2024-01-31,2024-02-29,2024-03-31,2024-04-30"
        }
    ]

Now, create an array variable dates_arr in the pipeline variables section and store the above date values as an array using below expression in a set variable activity.
@split(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Prop_0),',')


This will give the required dates array will be stored in dates_arr variable.

Now, take a For-each activity and give this @variables('dates_arr') variable as the expression to For-Each.
Inside For-Each, take a copy activity with your REST API dataset as source and Blob csv dataset as sink.
In the sink csv dataset, create a dataset parameter of string type.

Use this in the file name of the dataset as @dataset('targetfilename').

In the copy activity, give the below expression to this parameter.
@concat('Advances',item(),'.csv')


By Iterating through the dates_arr values, the result files with required names will be generated in each iteration like below.

If your source REST API URL also dynamic, that means, if it also needs the date at the end after keydate=, then you need to parameterize the URL in the REST dataset.
For sample, I took the below part as relative URL. First create a string type dataset parameter date and use that in the relative URL.
@concat('?$top=1000&$skip=0&$keydate=',dataset().date)


You need to give @item() as value for the above date parameter in the copy activity source inside For-loop.
